# Comparing Two divs Positions

Tags: jquery, css

My question is, how do you find the position of two '`<div>`' tags and compare them in an if statement? I did find a source that wrote something like this:

```
var obstacle = $('#obstacle').css('left', 'top')
var collider = $('img').css('left', 'top')

if ($('img').css(collider == obstacle) {
    $('div').css('background', 'blue')
}
```

But, this doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can get an element's position relative to the document with jQuery's [.offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/):

```
var obstacle_pos = $('#obstacle').offset();
console.log("left: " + obstacle_pos.left + ", top: " + obstacle_pos.top);
```

Comment: cheers, I did use this but I didn't know to add '.left' or '.top' to it untill DinoMyte reminded me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position()` method to get the position and then check for `left` attribute.

```
var obstacle = $("#obstacle").position().left;
var collider = $("img").position().left;

if (collider == obstacle) {
    $('div').css('background', 'blue')
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k93c6c5o/

Comment: I'd point out that position() gives you the position of elements relative to their parent. That can be a problem if both elements have different parents; offset() gives you the position relative to the document instead.

Comment: Cheers for that! although, it still doesn't seem to be working. it's always blue now.

http://jsfiddle.net/k93c6c5o/2/

what I want is, only when the '<img>' gets to the '<div>' does the '<div>' turn blue, otherwise it stays black!

Comment: You need to do the compare the position on keyup, not on document ready. http://jsfiddle.net/k93c6c5o/4/

Comment: DinoMyte, Thank you, I did not think about that at all.

Comment: Check the value of obstacleY and colliderY. When you move the superman over the black square, there is still a margin of decimal in their respective positions. Since you are animating it to a least of 1px, those values would never be the same.

Comment: +DinoMyte, Okay... I got it now, thanks for the help!